# How to generate multiple xls files with a for loop using content-type

Tags: php, excel, content-type, cycle

Before an apology, it is my first question and little English.

I need to generate multiple excel files with PHP, running a for loop. Each file must be renamed, the problem is that I only generate one in this case "ELEMENT THREE.xls".

In my file I got three lines :

```
CONTENT FILE ELEMENT ONE.xls
-------------------------------
CONTENT FILE ELEMENT TWO.xls
-------------------------------
CONTENT FILE ELEMENT THREE.xls
-------------------------------
```

This is my code :

```
$elements = array('ELEMENT ONE','ELEMENT TWO','ELEMENT THREE');

foreach ($elements as $element) {

    $table = "<table border='1'><tr><td>CONTENT FILE $element.xls</td></tr></table>";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$element.xls");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    echo utf8_decode($table);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are just echoing the table variable, it it showing only those three lines bcoz table variable only what you have assigned.  What do you want to generate in those three multiple xls files matters.  Be clear of what you exactly want, then maybe we can be of help